# Plates Template Engine - URI extension same as Twig 'pathFor'?

Tags: php, twig, slim, templating, plates

I'm working thru a tutorial on the Slim framework. The author uses Twig, and I'd prefer to use the Plates template engine. I've been able to modify all lessons to use the Plates template, until the author started using `baseUrl` and `pathFor` extensions.

I see that Plates has an extension called URI, which I think is synonymous with Twig's `pathFor`.

Unfortunately, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it enabled. Reading the documentation, I thought the following code would do it, but so far no luck.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App([
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ]
]);

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $plates = new League\Plates\Engine(__DIR__ . '/templates');
    $plates->loadExtension(new League\Plates\Extension\URI($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']));
    return $plates;
};

$app->get('/contact', function($request, $response) {
    return $this->view->render('contact');
});

$app->post('/contact', function($request, $response) {
    return $response->withRedirect('http://slim-local.com/contact/confirm');
})->setName('contact');

$app->get('/contact/confirm', function($request, $response) {
    return $this->view->render('contact_confirm');
});

$app->run();
```

And then in the template, the author used the `pathFor` extension to populate a form's action parameter. I am trying to use Plates' URI extention to do the same like so:

```
<form action="<?=$this->uri('contact')?>" method="post">
```

Has anybody used this template engine and the URI extension with Slim specifically? Am I mistaken that it is basically synonymous with Twig's `pathFor` extension? Should I give up and just use Twig? thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `URI` from the environment.

Slim 3 example:

```
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $plates = new \League\Plates\Engine(__DIR__ . '/templates');

    $uri = \Slim\Http\Uri::createFromEnvironment(new \Slim\Http\Environment($_SERVER));
    $plates->loadExtension(new \League\Plates\Extension\URI($uri->__toString()));

    return $plates;
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the quick and perfect answer. Not sure how I could have figured that out on my own yet, but thankfully there are plenty of smart and helpful folks such as yourself on StackOverflow to help.

Comment: BTW, what does __toString() accomplish? Having looked at it a bit now, I would have expected needing to use one of the variants of `getPath` although I still don't 100% understand WHY and HOW this all works.

Comment: [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) is a PHP magic method. This method is getting called if you want to cast an object to string. For example: `(string)$uri` is the same like this: `$uri->__toString()`